# Assign value to complex type without creating new instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

Below is my Type which i am using to return api response

```
public class ApiRespone
{
   public Response resp => new Response();
}

public class Response
{
    public MetaData metadata { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public object list { get; set; }
    public object item { get; set; }
}
```

when i try to assign value like below

```
var list = (IList<TModel>)Database.RepositoryT.List();
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            respone.resp.metadata = new MetaData
            {
                code = "404",
                status = "Success",
                message = "Records Not Found"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            respone.resp.metadata = new MetaData
            {
                code = "200",
                status = "Success",
                message = "Records Fetced Successfully"
            };
            respone.resp.data.list = list;
        }
        return respone;
```

In this code i get object refrence not set when setting value to metadata and data.list

I changed my response class by adding constructor under response class as follow

```
public class ApiRespone
{
   public Response resp => new Response();
}

public class Response
{
    public Response()
    {
        metadata = new MetaData();
        data = new Data();
    }
    public MetaData metadata { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public object list { get; set; }
    public object item { get; set; }
}
```

metadata and data are not initialized and object refrence error gone , but even after setting values its still null (metadata and data)

Any clue what is wrong here in data initialization?

**Update 1:**

As per tymtam suggestion modifying Type

```
public class ApiRespone
{
    public ApiRespone()
    {
        resp = new Response();
    }
    public Response resp { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Response()
    {
        metadata = new MetaData();
        data = new Data();
    }
    public MetaData metadata { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public object list { get; set; }
    public object item { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you setting `data` the same way as you're setting `metadata` with `respone.resp.data = new Data{ list = list }`?

Comment: Can you please supply the error from the build or run as text? It is important to understand where the `object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception happens.

Comment: @Jamiec even metadat is null after setting respone.resp.metadata = new MetaData{ values here}

Comment: @RasmusEdvardsen respone.resp.metadata = new MetaData {values set here} at this line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime you ask for `resp` you get a new empty object.

Please change:

```
public class ApiRespone
{
   public Response resp => new Response();
}
```

to

```
public class ApiRespone
{
   public Response()
   {
      resp = new Response();
   }

   public Response resp { get;}
}
```

Comment: This would explain why the second solution "works" - because everything is instantiated through constructors all the way down before primitive types.

Comment: @tyntam are you suggesting to wrap everything under ApiResponse() ?

Comment: No. I'm saying that `public Response resp => new Response();` will always give you a new object when ask for resp, and what you want is to initialise it once, in the constructor.

Comment: @tymtam Please check Updated 1 with new Type .

Comment: `public Response Resp { get; } = new Response();` would be more concise.

Comment: Are you saying that after you made the change, after ```respone.resp.metadata = new MetaData...``` the value of `respone.resp.metadata` is null? I find it hard to believe this.

Comment: After using constructor instead of => , its working (setting value in object and no object reference error)